# How to add time widget/picker?

Tags: google-app-maker

New appmaker user here.

I'm trying to port the work permits approval "app" I made with G Suite form+spreadsheet+GAS; users should enter the day, the start and end time of the permit.

I can see from the Forum Sample that the Date field type is a DateTime field type, so I can use it in my model.
The problem is I cannot find the time picker in the widgets, and the date box has no option to also enter the time.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time App Maker doesn't provide out of the box Time or Date/Time picker widgets, it means that you need to implement one by yourself. There are at least two ways to accomplish this task:

**App Maker way**

Wait and hope when App Maker will introduce Time or Date/Time picker widget or use existing App Maker widgets to emulate Time Picker. [Calendar Sample](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/calendar/) can be a good starting point:
[image: Calendar Sample]

**Hack into DOM/JS**

If you have no concerns about cross-browser compatibility and you are OK to get you hands dirty with DOM manipulation by javascript, creating events listeners and other cool stuff, then you can play with [HTML widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/display-widgets#html) and native [date/time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) or [time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) input, or even some third party library.

Comment: thnks, I overlooked the calendar sample! With this approach I can limit the hour picker to the working hours, and use 5 minutes step, which is a good thing for my goals.

Answer (score 1):

## Time Pickers for App Maker

I read your question and thought I'd try to role one of my own and this is what I came up with.  I put all of the buttons on a pageFragment and call it with `app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.timePicker2);`

I only use clientside script.

```
function updateOutput(){
  var h=app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.properties.hour||'00';
  var m=app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.properties.minute||'00';
  var s=app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.properties.second||'00';
  var t=h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.descendants.timeLBL.text=t;
  return t;
}
function updateHour(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.properties.hour=v;
  updateOutput();
}
function updateMinute(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.properties.minute=v;
  updateOutput();
}
function updateSecond(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.properties.second=v;
  updateOutput();
}
```

Here's what my time picker looks like:

[image]

Yes.  Adding all of the buttons is a nuisance but there are **a few features about AppMaker that make it more tolerable.**

First you can assign the TimePicker form properties which I use as global properties.  I had three hour,minute and second.

> Then after you add all of the hour buttons you can grab all of them at one time by clicking each one while holding down control on a windows machine and click on the onClick event and pick custom action and type this in `updateHour(widget.text);` the code completion won't give you text as an option but type it any way.

**I just figured out how to grab the buttons all a one time by pushing shift and selecting with the mouse**

Do the same thing with the minute and second buttons using `updateMinute(widget.text)` and `updateSecond(widget.text);` **This saves you a lot of time typing all of the functions into each widget control panel.**  Also you don't have to bother giving all of the buttons special names like I did.

But you might like to format them with the following css.

[image]

> And again you can grab all of the buttons at one time and change the following setting:

[image]

That way you can style all of the buttons at one time.

My save button just copies the final string into a label on the main panel.

```
app.pages.Testing.descendants.timeLBL2.text=app.pageFragments.TimePicker2.descendants.timeLBL.text;
app.closeDialog();
```

You will probably want to do something more elegant.

[Here's a demo:](https://youtu.be/LbdN37fDsNE) in preview mode.  Sorry about the 24 hour clock.  I always use this for my own stuff because it's so much easier and I like it.  You'll probably want AM & PM. I'll probably go back and do that too.

For an AM/PM Picker I used these functions:

```
function updateOutputAP(){
  var h=app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.hour||'00';
  var m=app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.minute||'00';
  var s=app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.second||'00';
  var ap=app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.ap||'  ';
  var t=h + ':' + m + ':' + s + ' ' + ap;
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.descendants.timeLBL.text=t;
  return t;
}
function updateHourPM(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.hour=v;
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.ap='PM';
  updateOutputAP();
}
function updateHourAM(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.hour=v;
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.ap='AM';
  updateOutputAP();
}
function updateMinuteAP(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.minute=v;
  updateOutputAP();
}
function updateSecondAP(v){
  app.pageFragments.TimePicker3.properties.second=v;
  updateOutputAP();
}
```

And this is what my picker looks like:

[image]

Now that I know how to pick the components easily with the mouse it was a break to make this change.

[Three AppMaker Time Pickers:](https://youtu.be/8DaTI1QtaI0)

Answer (score 0):

One simple option would be to simply use a textbox and set the validation in the model field. 
You can update your Date object on save or just use as is depending on your application. You get the benefit of auto validation errors in the UI to guide your user and it takes only seconds to set up.

Regex:

```
\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))
```

[image: Model Feild]